# Is there an alternative to repeatedly sending Large prompts to Chat completion API when there is only minor tweaks to subsequent prompts?

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I have a prompt with messages that are rather large in size because of the context content I provide with them. It will be repeatedly reused with chat model albeit with minor tweaks in subsequent calls after the first one.

The only way I am seeing to do this is to provide the full but tweaked messages again and again drastically increasing my token cost. Is there an solution to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment two options would be best suited for you ..

1. Instead for large messages you can send summarized version of your message. If suppose the response from model is not as per your requirement, you can resend small message for clarification.
2. Your prompt should mention about referring the context history from previous conversations, this will again have short messages and you can resend short queries for clarification.